# TP-Link Archer C2 DSL connection

Tags: router, dsl, broadband

I am using a DSL connection for my broadband, when I plug the cable into the blue port labeled internet, it doesn't connect to the broadband like a normal hub would do, I am aware that I probably need an extra thing to go with it, like a DSL modem, is there any other way to connect it with out having to go out and buy a DSL modem?

Comment: Your router is not a DSL modem. You need to buy a DSL modem.

Comment: But isn't that just like plugging a router into another router?

Comment: Most DSL modems can be configured to act as either plain modems or combination modem-routers (a.k.a. modem-gateways). But the gateway features of DSL modems are usually inferior to a good quality standalone gateway. So it's best to buy a good quality DSL modem that doesn't try to be a wireless router or anything, tell it to be a plain pass-through (bridging) modem, and put a good quality home gateway or wireless router behind it.

Comment: Some modems have built in routers. In general routers do not contain modems.